# Can I build a gravel driveway over sand?

Tags: driveway, gravel

There is a large quantity of sand where I would like to build a gravel drive. The sand is not super deep, only an inch or two at its deepest points, but I cannot find any quick way to remove it. Much of it is compacted as well. I was considering just dumping 4 inches of #8 gravel on top of this sand base, which like I said, seems quite stable even in the rain. My big questions are:

Will dumping this gravel over the sand weight it down and stop the sand from blowing around when it gets windy? I'm trying to keep sand from getting all over my cars.

Are there any inherent problems with doing this? (Note: I don't need this driveway to last forever, a couple years of life would be just fine)

Any other suggestions?

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Why is there sand? And what is under that sand?

Comment: The rock will probably work its way down and some of the sand will move up over time. The sand may help to lock the rock together, The question I would ask is how deep is "not super deep".

Comment: If you use #8 it will never stop settling. Use 3/4" crushed stone. If the stones have rounded edges, you're looking at the wrong pile.

Answer (score 1):

For me living in the desert a sand yard is pretty common.   Putting gravel on top of the sand here to add a bit of firmness is also common.
So as previously commented how much sand and what is under it will affect success and how long it lasts before sand comes through (if it does).   The gravel will work into the sand, but this is not bad at all (concrete is sand, gravel and a cement, 2 out of the 3).
Two factors on how long it lasts before the sand does appear on top again will depend on water content, how much gravel is laid, how thick the sand is and compaction.
To start your effort, water the sand well and give it a day or so to soak and harden.  If a compaction machine is available compact it when damp.
Lay your gravel on top, wet and compact it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use crushed Oyster shells.
The shell are very compatible with the sand and will blend in with the sand to make a drive almost as hard as cement.

Comment: I like the idea but oyster shells in my neck of the woods would be more expensive than asphalt or concrete.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of or considered crushed bluestone? Fairly inexpensive, gives a locking effect and stays put such as the edge/end.

I have a farmer friend who would disc his driveway (roughly 100'x30') after every rainy season and this turned the soil to a fine sand.

He wanted something that would form to his slightly rolling grade, drain properly, easy to walk on and maintain, and be somewhat quite. Concrete was not an option (rolling grade) and he didn't like asphalt.

He used bluestone gravel. SO far no maintenance required, no sinkage, same color as when purchased, quite, pretty and very comfortable to walk on even with thin sandals. I was very surprised, almost amazed and wondered why it is not used more often.

Roughly 2 1/2" -  3' depth is what he used.
[image]

NOTE: Bluestone is one of only a couple crushed stones that meets code for Wheelchair Accessibility.
[image]